# Return Character from Numeric Field using Cast & Coalesce

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

Relatively basic SQL user, apologies if this is a simple question but need a little help to tidy up the output of a fairly complex script I have been given.

I have a number of columns being returned for which where there is a NULL, I want to replace all NULL's with a standard set of characters, currently "---". Using `ISNULL` works for most columns. However, for some columns we are looking at 2 tables to find a value so have after doing some research on here, I have modified a line I am having trouble with as follows:

**Previous**

```
isnull (ff.ff_sales,aa.ff_sales) as 'Total Revenue'
```

**Latest**

```
cast(coalesce(ff.ff_sales,aa.ff_sales,'') as FLOAT) as 'Total Revenue'
```

The initial line returned 'NULL' if both ff.ff_sales & aa.ff_sales were empty, now with the latest line using cast & coalesce I get '0'. However, I am trying to achieve a situation where I get '---' as per all other fields where a NULL exists. I don't want it to return '0' for a Sales field as this is misleading. I have tried using `VARCHAR` instead of `FLOAT` but am unsure if this is the right thing to do at this stage?

1st column is using `ISNULL`, 2nd column current output with cast & coalesce, 3rd column is what I want to get to:

```
Total Revenue   Total Revenue     Total Revenue
67755           67755             67755
6.123           6.123             6.123
494.75          494.75            494.75
0               0                 0
1139909         1139909           1139909
12346.45        12346.45          12346.45
129.866         129.866           129.866
NULL            0                 ---
NULL            0                 ---
554             554               554
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot cast '---' as a `float`. And I would keep total revenue as a numeric type rather than text, unless this will be used directly in a report, as a read-only field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case to decide what should be output in this scenario, like so:

```
select 
case 
 when isnull (ff.ff_sales,aa.ff_sales) is null then '---' 
 else cast(isnull (ff.ff_sales,aa.ff_sales) as varchar) 
end as 'Total Revenue'
```

This will force the output to be returned as `varchar` though, because you cannot cast '---' as a numeric type.

Alternatively, you could just let the value be NULL in DB, and in your presentation layer, replace a `DBNull` or equivalent value with '---'. This will let you keep total revenue as a numeric field at the DB level.

Comment: Thanks @shree.pat That works; though I noticed one of the fields with a particularly large number (Japanese Yen) now shows 1.13991e+006 instead of 1139909 (as previously displayed above), I guess this is a byproduct of using varchar? The DBNull is an interesting option which I will explore.